# Command property exposing not working in UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a UserControl that wraps a button:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Controls.BigButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Button Command="{Binding Command}">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
            <ContentPresenter Width="40" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,5" Content="{Binding Icon}" />
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel> 
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

It exposes some properties in code-behind file:

```
public partial class BigButton : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(BigButton));
    public string Text 
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(UIElement), typeof(BigButton));
    public UIElement Icon
    {
        get { return (UIElement)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BigButton));
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public BigButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Then I add this control into view this way:

```
<controls:BigButton
    Icon="{StaticResource IconStop}"
    Text="Stop"
    Command="{Binding StopCommand}" />
```

And it doesn't goddamnd executes its command. Icon is in place as well as text, so at least some exposed properties are working right. But command isn't. Command itself seems to be fine, I can execute it using

```
<Button Command="{Binding StopCommand}" />
```

So I wonder, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your BigButton would inherit parent's DataContext but you explicitly set it to itself:

```
 DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

and because of that when you set

```
Command="{Binding StopCommand}"
```

it kicked off seeking in BigButton's DataContext so no result was found what is supposed to be reflected in Output as error message. Solution is to get access to parent's DataContext by setting:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Command}" Name="MyButton">
```

and

```
   public BigButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.MyButton.DataContext = this;
        }
```

I refer you to this [article](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html).

Comment: Yep, somewhy I thought that "internal" DataContext will not interfere with view's DataContext. So text and Icon bindings worked because they are static, not searched inside the actual DataContext.

Comment: Precisely, Text you set explicitly and resource was found by going up the tree first from UserControl and then Window so in both cases DataContext was not used.